# how to fix un-representable DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used the below codes in my project. when i add "13" line it throw exception like "Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime." Points contains two value X and Y. ie.. **Points.Add(X, Y)** . I have used **X** as Date format and **Y** is double value

```
ser1.Points.Add(new DateTime(2000, 02, 11), 21);
        ser1.Points.Add(new DateTime(2000, 09, 14), 25);
        ser1.Points.Add(new DateTime(2001, 02, 11), 30);
        ser1.Points.Add(new DateTime(2001, 09, 16), 33);
        ser1.Points.Add(new DateTime(2002, 02, 07), 23);
        ser1.Points.Add(new DateTime(2002, 09, 07), 28);
        ser1.Points.Add(new DateTime(2003, 02, 11), 30);
        ser1.Points.Add(new DateTime(2003, 09, 14), 38);
        ser1.Points.Add(new DateTime(2004, 02, 06), 35);
        ser1.Points.Add(new DateTime(2004, 09, 06), 38);
        ser1.Points.Add(new DateTime(2005, 02, 11), 30);
        ser1.Points.Add(new DateTime(2005, 09, 11), 27);

        ser1.Points.Add(new DateTime(2006, 02, 29), 25);//getting error add this line
```

Anyone could hep me

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Comment: You can use `DateTime.DaysInMonth(int year, int month)` as a check before adding the date

Answer (score 5):

There are **28** days in year 2006 **not 29**, that is why you are getting error. You are giving date that is not present in calender.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was probably not a leap year that year. Feb 29 is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

**2006** was not a **leap year**.So there are only 28 days in Feb(02) month.

You probably need to change it like this:

```
ser1.Points.Add(new DateTime(2006, 02, 28), 25);
```